# Error encountered when running batch file - was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have encountered an error when running a batch file. It goes like this, I run `test-setup.cmd` which calls another batch file `test-env.cmd`

`test-setup.cmd` calls by using this line:

```
call %SCRIPT_HOME%\test-env.cmd
```

where `SCRIPT_HOME` is set up as `SCRIPT_HOME=%~dp0`

`test-env.cmd` has this line:

```
if [%TEST_HOME%] == [] set TEST_HOME=D:\Program Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final
```

After running the `test-setup.cmd` a message appears like this:

```
Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final was unexpected at this time
```

Note that I have setup the `TEST_HOME` in the system environment variables.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: I think you need to put `D:\Program Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final` in double quotes as it has a space in it

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried it but it did not worked - TEST_HOME="D:\Program Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final"

I also tried to enclose the whole line with quotes but it also returns the same error

"TEST_HOME=D:\Program Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final"

Comment: Why `Set SCRIPT_HOME` to `%~dp0`? _(What benefit is there in typing 13 characters to replace 5)_. You say that `%TEST_HOME%` is set up in the system environment, that means that `[%TEST_HOME%]` will not be empty and therefore the new path cannot be set as it's new value. With the information you have provided I would not be confident that any of the rest of your scripts are robust enough to provide you with solutions. Please edit your question appending the full content of both of your batch files.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `if` command is incorrect.  It would work if `%TEST_HOME%` didn't contain any spaces, but since it does you *must* use double quotes:

```
if "%TEST_HOME%" == "" set TEST_HOME=D:\Program Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final
```

Mind you, since you're just testing to see whether the variable exists, it would be a lot more efficient to do that directly:

```
if not defined TEST_HOME set TEST_HOME=D:\Program Files\Test\test-02.2.3.Final
```